# What is equivalent of login_required() in Masonite?

Tags: python, login-required, masonite

In Django, we use `login_required()` decoratir around the view, so that  login is required to pass the request,, usually  it redirects  to  login  page?

How to do this in Masonite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Route middleware can be used to only allow authenticated users to access a given route or view of course.

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def my_view(request):
    ...
```

Could be written like this:

```
from masonite.helpers.routes import get
...

ROUTES = [
    ...
    get('/home', 'HomeController@my_view').middleware('auth')
]
```